# How to remove page numbers with 'amsart'

Tags: page-numbering

How can I remove the page numbers in 'amsart' articles?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{amsart}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\title[Test]{Test}
\maketitle
Please remove the page number!
\end{document}
```

Comment: add `\thispagestyle{empty}` just after `\maketitle`

Answer (score 3):

`amsart`, like many similar document classes, includes a `\thispagestyle` command as part of `\maketitle` which overrides your `\pagestyle{empty}` on the first page (you should see no page numbers on subsequent pages). Putting `\thispagestyle{empty}` after `\maketitle` will override that and give you no page number on the first page as well.